# How to make the cells of a column of a Data-Table editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I want to make the cells of a column of a Data-Table editable. Does the Data Table plugin support any such feature?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the recommended way: http://editor.datatables.net/

Also supports [inline editing](http://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple.html)

This editor comes directly from the authors of datatables, so the usage should be pretty familiar and easy.